# iptables: Outgoing Traffic gets redirected to local Port

Tags: debian, iptables, kvm-virtualization

I am using following iptables script on my debian machine:

```
#!/bin/sh


IPT="/sbin/iptables"

# Flush old rules, old custom tables
$IPT --flush
$IPT --delete-chain

# Set default policies for all three default chains
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P FORWARD DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

# Enable free use of loopback interfaces
$IPT -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# All TCP sessions should begin with SYN
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j DROP

# Accept inbound TCP packets
$IPT -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT

# Accept inbound ICMP messages
$IPT -A INPUT -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -j ACCEPT

#VM Windows
$IPT -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
$IPT -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
$IPT -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d  192.168.122.178 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d  192.168.122.160 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -I FORWARD -o virbr0 -d  192.168.122.105 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25300 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.178:25300
$IPT -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.160:22
$IPT -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 26300 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.105:26300
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -j MASQUERADE
$IPT -A FORWARD -o virbr0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
$IPT -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

I have 3 virtual machines, virtualised with kvm. Somehow i managed to f*** up my iptables script. Everytime I try to connect to anything on port 80/443 the traffic gets redirected to the local machine. I got to know this, because one of the VMs is a Windows Server and I had IIS running at this time. Every website I tried to access redirected to my IIS running locally. The curious thing is, it looks like it is only redirecting the outgoing traffic on port 80/443.

Comment: You should not save firewall rules that were generated by libvirt. Let libvirt manage its own firewall rules; if you need to change them, use [libvirt's mechanisms](https://libvirt.org/firewall.html) to do so. And this firewall script looks like something that originated with an old, poor Internet tutorial; you should consider replacing it with something better supported by your distro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*edit: If you're using libvirt, you should use those management mechanisms first and not this answer.*

You should try a couple things to make your NAT rules more restricted.

My first guess is your POSTROUTING rule should only be your internal addresses.

```
$IPT -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Additionally, you should further restrict your PREROUTING rules so as not to bounce your internal traffic around, eg.

```
$IPT -t nat -I PREROUTING ! -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -p tcp --dport 25300 -j DNAT --to 192.168.122.178:25300
```